# Python 3.x and Davinci Resolve

Tags: python-3.x, libraries, davinci-resolve

First time working with an API that isn't part of normal python lib that isn't installed using -pip. I'm using VS Code and trying to get python to import the API. But I'm coming up short. The Davinci Resolve documentation says to use these lines of code to get a script working.

```
RESOLVE_SCRIPT_API= "%PROGRAMDATAtest%\Blackmagic Design\DaVinci Resolve\Support\Developer\Scripting\"
RESOLVE_SCRIPT_LIB= "C:\Program Files\Blackmagic Design\DaVinci Resolve\fusionscript.dll"
PYTHONPATH= "%PYTHONPATH%;%RESOLVE_SCRIPT_API%\Modules\"
```

But I can't seem to find the right place for them. I've tired in my script file. I've tried creating a virtual environment and them in that way but that still didn't work. I think the best way for this to work would be VS Code to natively point to the folder path of the API. I've found the 'workspace.jason' file but I'm unsure how to add / append the above path strings to get it to work.

This was my best attempt at it.

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Python",
            "dr_API": "%PROGRAMDATA%\Blackmagic Design\DaVinci Resolve\Support\Developer\Scripting"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
            
        ]
    }
}
```

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

PS. I'm self taught so if this is something that is dumb to the formally trained, I apologize in advance.

I've found the Davinci Resolve documentation here:

[DaVinciResolve-API-Docs](https://deric.github.io/DaVinciResolve-API-Docs/)

Comment: Speaking as someone who knows nothing about VS Code but does know Python -- you can always change `sys.path` to contain the extra directory instead of relying on `PYTHONPATH` to be used for lookups. Similarly, you can set `os.environ['RESOLVE_SCRIPT_API']` and `os.environ['RESOLVE_SCRIPT_LIB']` before you try to do the first `import`. BTW, _do_ make sure the interpreter you're using is binary-compatible (same version, built with the same compiler with the same ABI target). Also, you may need to expand PROGRAMDATA yourself if you do it this way.

Comment: (I have Resolve Studio installed, but on MacOS rather than Windows, and I have no interest in interacting in any way with Microsoft products -- so I'm not in a place to reproduce the problem).